# Add custom nuget feed from the Package Manager Console (PowerShell)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, nuget

Is there a way to add custom nuget feeds without going through the GUI? I know I can open the "Manage Nuget Packages" dialog, go to Settings, and add from there. I'm looking for a way to add a feed through PowerShell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could modify nuget visual studio extensions configuration file (located by default at `C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`) with PowerShell

Comment: @JosiahRuddell Did you come up with a PowerShell solution that can open the NuGet.config file and add nodes under packageSources if they are not already there?  I want to create a ps1 file for my team to setup a couple internal NuGet feeds (3rd-party cache and internal packages).  I'm sure I could do it in C#, but I'd prefer an all-PowerShell version and I'm not a PowerShell expert yet.

Comment: FYI, you can also use %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\NuGet to make it more generic.